# Sharepoint to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm not a sharepoint developer and are only looking for a overview solution. We have is two internal sharepoint sites. One is a document repository and the other is the intranet.

What I need is to provide a highlevel solution on what technology to use to enable the intranet to fetch documents from the document repository.

Preferrably authentication should flow, giving the user Single Sign On. We're using NTLM internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options:
1- Open the source document library in explorer, copy all documents and paste in destination document library in intranet site! It is simple, however isn't an automatic method!
2- Use PowerShell, this link is really helpful: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Copy-all-SharePoint-Files-0999c53f
3- Personally, I did this task programmatically using VS
4- I'm not sure but may be you can do it with BCD(Business Connectivity Data)

Answer (score 0):

You can Use any of the available API's - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/jj164060.aspx

I prefer using [OpenBinaryDirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537083.aspx) using Client Object Model as this allows retriving files of larger sizes (but < 2GB).

Answer (score 0):

We can try using Visual studio and build a WCF or something to access the document repository. The front end can be any client side technology like Silverlight, html5 etc.

Check this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd440954(v=office.12).aspx

We have implemented it in a similar fashion on SP 2007. Options improve with SharePoint 2010 and 2013. 2013 has many plug-ins that integrate well with Microsoft OneDrive etc.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use the following three method for this purpose:

1. REST Services
2. Object Oriented Model
3. CMOS

But all these three solutions will work only when your server is same.

I mean, you have got no choice but to use the same server to make these solutions work for you.